# Query Firestore collection based on negation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are developing a messaging system where the users are able to block each other. This means we need the ability to query message where the author is not blocked.

Pseudo: Select * from messages where author_id not in {list_of_blocked_ids}

Since Firestore does not support array_not_contains or any other negation-methods we are quite unsure how to structure this data to be able to make this query.

Any help structuring this information about blocked users is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, according to the official documentation regarding [Query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> Cloud Firestore **does not support** the following types of queries:

- > Queries with a **!=** clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example,
  >   although the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported,
  >   you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with
  >   the clause where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause
  >   where("age", ">", 30).

So with other words, there is no `!=` (not equal to) operator in Firestore nor a `arrayNotContains()` function. The only option that you have is to split your query into a `greater-than` and a `less-than` query and then it will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate on how to make this query? We have a list of blocked author-ids and want to show all conversatioins where the author id is not any of these blocked author ids. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer, and ask another question if something else comes up.

Answer (score -1):

In each "conversation" document, put subcollections - one called "messages" and one called "blocklist". Assign the blocked users `uid` as key to boolean value of `true`. Use Firestore Rules to enforce the blocking, rather than a query.

PSEUDO: allow read, write if this uid is not found in this conversations blocklist

Comment: Thank you for your answer - unfortunately this will not work. We need to be able to  query all conversations where the post author is not blocked. We cannot do this with as the Firestore documentation states: "When writing queries to retrieve documents, keep in mind that security rules are not filters—queries are all or nothing. "