# Querying a number outside of range with cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get all documents within a certain number of timezones.  For example, want to get all documents with timezones +/- 2 hours of UTC-8.  Currently Im storing the timezones as minutes from UTC.  So Pacific time zone would be stored in the database as -420 (7 hours or 420 minutes west of UTC).  So initial thought would be just do something like this (using Flutter cloud_firestore):

```
int west = timeZone - 120;
int east = timeZone + 120;
query.where('timezone', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: west)
        .where('timezone', isLessThanOrEqualTo: east);
```

Problem with this is the edge cases where the timezone is around the international date line and how to wrap it so it includes the other edge.  I can easily get the new boundaries with something like this:

```
int west = timeZone - timeZoneDiff >= -720 ? timeZone - timeZoneDiff : 720 + (timeZone - timeZoneDiff + 720);
int east = timeZone + timeZoneDiff <= 720 ? timeZone + timeZoneDiff : -720 + (timeZone + timeZoneDiff - 720);
```

But unless I missed something in the documentation Firestore doesnt seem to have an or clause with their where statements.  So need to get a number that is not within a range so

where x is not between y and z

Comment: Please reword `Problem with this is the edge cases where the timezone is around the international date line and how to wrap it so it includes the other edge`. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52847107/1620779) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with a single query, as Firestore does not have logical OR queries.  You would have to perform two queries: one for everything less than the lower number, and another for everything greater than the higher value.

Comment: Ok, that was what I was thinking.  Do you think it would be better to do two queries or filter results on client side for scaling purposes

Comment: Try them both, and pick the one that performs the best with your data.  I don't know what your data looks like, or how your app might benefit from requesting more data than required.